# How I prove this function does not have zero derivation

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a function and I want to state that this function does not have a null derivation.

> $$x\ln(e+\frac{1}{x})$$

The first derivation is

> $$\ln(\frac{1}{x}+e)-\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x}+e)x}$$

How do I prove that this derivation is never zero?
Please in some way that a student can understand :)
thank you

Comment: Well, it looks like $f'(x) > 1$ for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and also that it approaches $1$ when $x \to \pm \infty$. Perhaps you can rewrite the derivative so that this is clear?

Comment: Calculate the second derivative. You will get something in the form $-\frac{1}{g(x)}$, and there is no way to make this expression equal $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain we are dealing with is $]-\infty , -\frac{1}{e}[ \cup ]0 , +\infty[$. 
We can write the double derivative as 
$$f''(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x\left(\mathrm{e}x+1\right)^2}$$
Note that for $x>0$, we have that $f''(x) < 0$ hence $f'(x)$ is strictly decreasing. Note that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f'(x)  = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f'(x)  = +1 > 0$. So in $]0,+\infty[$ the function $f'(x)$ decreases from $+\infty$ to $+1$.

Note that for $x<0$, we have that $f''(x) > 0$ hence $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing. Note that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f'(x)  = 1$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\frac{1}{e}} f'(x)  = +\infty$.  So, in $]-\infty , -\frac{1}{e}[$ the function $f'(x)$ increases from $1$ to $+\infty$.

Now, use your imagination :)

Comment: Wow thank you, sir.

Must notice I was kinda confused by your brackets in intervals but then I recalled my lecturer who told us that in France you use reversed brackets. :)

Comment: haha that's right @naruto25